# Control POSIX time difference output in R

Tags: r, datetime

In `R` I have two strings:

```
t <- c("2010-01-01 00:01:02", "2010-01-01 00:02:02")
```

which I convert to POSIX datetimes:

```
dt <- as.POSIXct(t)
```

Taking the difference of the two `dt[2] - dt[1]` gives:

```
Time difference of 1 mins
```

Cool.  But how do I force the time difference to be in, say, seconds?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
> difftime(dt[2], dt[1], units="secs")
Time difference of 60 secs
```